# Correctly display x-datetime axis D3.js

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I would like to display candlesticks chart dynamically with dates of candles on x axis.

When I use x = scaleBand().domain(data.map(d=>d.date)) it displays correctly, but I would like to leave some space for new candles…

I would like to display candlesticks chart dynamically with dates of candles on x axis.

When I use x = scaleBand().domain(data.map(d=>d.date)) it displays correctly, but I would like to leave some space for new candles. If I will use something like

const x_axis = axisBottom(x);
const xAxisGroup = selection.append(‘g’).attr(‘transform’, ‘translate(${-dimentions.width/3}, ${dimentions.height}).call(x_axis)

then I can get this space. But how can I get dates for this left space? Dates should be from the first candle to now. So I would like to leave space for candles, but xAxis should be full, without space at the end.

Comment: Please post your code and a picture of the desired result as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247334/d3-js-dates-x-axis